# Tricentis Tosca, Getting error while running TemplateInstance, attached image below

Tags: tosca

I'm getting this error:

> The state  is not a valid state for a CheckBox.
> Parameter name: value

while running TemplateInstance.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Never mind , It's got resolved by my self, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes only accept boolean values (either you select one of them from the dropdown, or you pass a parameter which is 'True' or 'False').